# Lighttpd and Python web page: Cannot not convert data into an integer

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, lighttpd

please, I making a easy python web page without any framework. But I have problem if I tried to get some value from tuple

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
# Some code here 
# ....
# Months in slovak language
months = ('Január', 'Február', 'Marec', 'Apríl', 'Máj', 'Jún', 'Júl', 'August', 'September', 'Október', 'November', 'December')
month = int(last_day_of_month(today).strftime("%m"))
# some code here
# ...
# print ("\t" + '<title>{0} {1}' + str(months[month-1]) + ' ' + str(year) + '</title>')
```

Here I got error:

**Cannot not convert data into an integer**

It works only if I months defined in ascii, something like:

```
months = ('Janury', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
```

This works right. Of course, file is in **UTF-8** encoding and in python console works fine (print whole page without any problem)

Maybe this is not problem of a python but maybe it's a problem of my **Lighttpd** local server. Could be?

I tried any tricks in python like forced convert to int with **int()** function or printing month with format:

```
print ("\t" + '<title>{0} {1}</title>'.format(months[1], year))
```

Any ideas where could be a problem?

Thanks for any ideas

EDIT: Whole code with function defitions is here:

https://pastebin.com/B9hkNFYC

Comment: What is the implementation of `last_day_of_month`? Does it really return a `int`? You can compute the last day of month with: `calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]`.

Comment: hello, yes. It's return always int **return date.replace(month=date.month + 1, day = 1) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)** But I'm sure that problem isn't in this function implementation. I tried next tricks and I got error in every every non-ascii string. for example **print ('á')** returns error **Cannot not convert data into an integer** . Otherwise **print('a')** it's totally OK

Comment: Please provide the whole stack trace